# Parsing matrix from JSON message

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to Javascript and am not very familiar with its wide range of libraries.

I have a Numpy (Python) matrix serialized into a JSON message, but want to decode the matrix from this JSON message in Javascript.

Is there a well-known JS library that does this? If so, what is the exact data structure I get from decoding? A multi-dimension array in Javascript?

Comment: [`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)?

Comment: or if you dont have jQuery - JSON.parse(jsonString). Check out [http://www.json.org/js.html](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can unserialize the JSON string with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```
var matrix = JSON.parse(numpyString);
```

Once you've done that, you can explore the format of the resulting object in the console in a web browser.

```
console.dir(matrix);
```